# Python loop taking considerable time to perform cosine similarity reuters documentation

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, cosine-similarity

Python 3.6

I am trying to calculate the cosine similarity of the standard Reuters documentation of roughly 10,000 documents.

I have created a dictionary with

```
full_docs_id = reuters.fileids()
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize);
vec_full_docs = vectorizer.fit_transform(full_docs_id)

newdict = dict(zip(full_docs_id,vec_full_docs))
```

I then run the loop but i'm not getting any outputs after running this for many hours

```
com = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(lambda: {'weight':0}))

for key, value in newdict.items():
    for first, second in newdict.items():
        cosine_similarities = cosine_similarity(value,second).flatten()
        com[key][first]['weight'] = cosine_similarities[0]
```

The reason for the weight is that I need this to input into a network analysis.

Is there a better way to this. This is my first major Python project.

Thanks

Comment: which version of python?

Comment: what will you get if you put a print statement, such as print(key, first), in the inner loop?

Comment: @Shiping if I add in the print(key,first) it is printing the combination of that document with every other and is running sample here
test/14888 training/7366. What does this mean, its working?

Comment: @colin.kane that means it's not stuck at certain step. so the complexity is O(n^2) and requires 100 million calculations and it could take many hours to complete. but all the steps are independent and you may consider some parallel algorithms (i don't think it's too complicated to do).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm guessing right that you are using Python 2: Try changing these two lines to use iteritems() and let me know if it speeds up for you:

```
for key, value in newdict.iteritems():
    for first, second in newdict.iteritems():
```

Comment: Probably, before posting this as an answer, you should ask if Python 2 is being used. Generally, I assume Python 3 unless there is a Python 2 tag.